# How to remove unnecessary tags generated by neocomplete plugin of vim in my code snippet?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-neocomplete

I am using Neocomplete and vdav/chef-vim plugin to write chef code using a snippet. I see the following snippet:

```
 # Template resource
template "/path/to/file" do # Path to the file
  <`2:#`>cookbook <`3:nil`> # Specify the cookbook where the template is located, default is current cookbook
  <`4:#`>source <`5:nil`> # Template source file. Found in templates/default for the cookbook
  <`6:#`>variables <`7`> # Variables to use in the template
  <`8:#`>local <`9:false`> # Is the template already present on the node?
  <`10:#`>backup <`11:5`> # How many backups of this file to keep. Set to false if you want no backups.
  <`12:#`>owner <`13`> # The owner for the file
  <`14:#`>group <`15`> # The group owner of the file (string or id)
  <`16:#`>mode <`17`> # The octal mode of the file (4-digit format)
  <`18:#`>content <`19:nil`> # A string to write to the file. This will replace any previous content if set

  <`20:#`><`21:action :create`> # Create the file (Default)
  <`22:#`><`23:action :delete`> # Delete this file
  <`24:#`><`0:action :touch`> # Touch this file (update the mtime/atime)
end
```

The code snippet however should have been as follows:

```
# Template resource
template "/path/to/file" do # Path to the file
  cookbook nil # Specify the cookbook where the template is located, default is current cookbook
  source nil # Template source file. Found in templates/default for the cookbook
  variables  # Variables to use in the template
  local false # Is the template already present on the node?
  backup 5 # How many backups of this file to keep. Set to false if you want no backups.
  owner  # The owner for the file
  group  # The group owner of the file (string or id)
  mode  # The octal mode of the file (4-digit format)
  content nil # A string to write to the file. This will replace any previous content if set

  action :create # Create the file (Default)
  action :delete # Delete this file
  action :touch # Touch this file (update the mtime/atime)
end
```

How do I remove this additional symbolic *<`#`> text <`#:text`>* text generated in Vim?

I tried using *nnoremap  :let _s=@/:%s/\s+$//e:let @/=_s* to remove it, however it did not help. May be I am not doing it correctly too.

My .vimrc and .vimrc.local can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/MN8XXD41).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
:%s/<[^>]*>//g
```

If you want to use it multiple times make a map for it like

```
nnoremap g<space> :%s/<[^>]*>//g<CR>
```

So you can use it by pressing g (you can change that of course)